# My telegram bot does not support Persian language

Tags: python-2.7, python-telegram-bot

I built a telegram bot with Python-Telegram-bot, and I want to send a bot to a user in Persian when the user sends /Start ;but the bot does not work.
My Code:

```
from telegram.ext import Updater,CommandHandler
updater = Updater(token='TOKEN')

def start_method(bot,update):
bot.sendMessage(update.message.chat_id,"سلام")

start_command = CommandHandler('start', start_method)
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(start_command)

updater.start_polling()
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use unicode text in your code, you have to specify the file encoding according to [PEP 263](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/).

Place this comment at the beginning of your script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

You can also use Python 3, which has much better unicode support in general and assumes utf-8 encoding for source files by default.

Answer (score 0):

First, need to use a `urllib`. If your text is something like txt1, you need to quote it first and then send it as a message. like this:

```
from urllib.parse import quote
......

txt1 = 'سلام. خوش آمدید!'
txt = quote(txt1.encode('utf-8'))
```